# How to get app latest version from PlayStore/AppStore react native

Tags: android, ios, react-native, mobile

I need to compare my app's version with the latest version from PlayStore/AppStore. I used react-native-version-check but it's not working properly for my app. 
Is there a way to call directly to the stores which will contain the version in the response? (using react native)

Comment: I don't think there is anything native that is right for you. You can instead, for example, do it with this: https://github.com/kimxogus/react-native-version-check

Comment: thanks. I tried to use it, but it doesn't have code support right now and it's maintainable from the owners.

Comment: not maintainable*

Answer (score 0):

I implemented your scenario using a mixture of react-native-config and react-native-appstore-version-checker.

The installed app version I used react-native-config to create an app version variable that I retrieve with: `Config.REACT_APP_VERSION`

For the app store version, I used the react-native-appstore-version-checker module. The installation instructions worked great.

For my use-case, I wanted to do something different if the upgrade was a major or minor, so I then split the two app versions and did major/minor/build comparisons.